# Pandas assign does not change Dataframe as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Jupyter code:

```
display(df)
trade_datetime = df.date.apply(lambda x: x.to_datetime())
display(trade_datetime)
df.assign(new_date=trade_datetime)
display(df)
```

the date column is a series of custom objects that has a `to_datetime` function. apply does what I'd expect, but I cannot get the dataframe to change with the assign function. can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong here?

[image: output]

Comment: `.assign` doesn't alter the DataFrame... it returns a *new* DataFrame with the assignments

Comment: It doesn't say in the docs, but can you pass `inplace=True`?

Comment: Thank you both! @JeffTilton: No, that doesn't work. No error, but also no effect. using the returned dataframe works of course - I think I missed that because I first read that DataFrames are mutable, so I assumed assign to be inplace based on its name.

Comment: I agree assign implicitly sounds like it would be done inplace